# Serve node.js app without sudo (apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, node.js, apache2

**Situation**: I have an access to a directory 'public' on a server (which is no my). Content of this directory is public by www.size.com/~user, if I place there html file (for example index.html) browser shows me html page. If I place there an image it shows me and a hierarchical structure of 'public'. That's all I can do - I can't edit configuration files of apache, I can't use sudo.

On the server is node.js. When I execute node.js application and I use `curl adress:8080` (from the server) its works fine (if I use `curl www.size.com/~user` with or without port it doesn't work). But I can't find out a way to return right response in browsers from any device. I have tried many configurations of .htaccess, but I got 'Internal Server Error' almost every time.

How to force apache to return node.js app?

**I want**: www.size.com/~user to return result of node.js app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You would need to change configuration of Apache to act as a reverse proxy for your node application, so that requests for `www.size.com/~user` are forwarded to `localhost:8080`. This cannot be achieved with `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Oh, that are bad news. And the only place where is possible to change configuration of Apache is /etc/apache2 I can't have some file in 'public', which would override the part of Apache configuration right? Or is there something, that I can do as non-root?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible - as an administrator, you wouldn't want your users to freely change your configuration, would you?